# How to pass value from rich text box to another rich text box

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WPF (C#)
I have two rich text box,
I want to type in first rich text box and press enter, it will displays in the second rich text box.

please help me with the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set event richtextbox1 KeyDown

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text;
                }
            }
```

Try this :)

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key != System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter) return;

            var textRange = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
            string rtf;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                textRange.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                rtf = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }



            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtf));
            richTextBox2.SelectAll();
            richTextBox2.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your guide, but it doesn't work because I'm not using window form. I'm using Window Presentation Form (WPF).

Answer (score 1):

on the enter press key 
and set the other textbox text property

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        richTextBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text;
    }
}
```